# Enter to reliably submit html form

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a form with text input + gradient-shaded button with onclick='this.form.submit()' (plus some hidden inputs).

In all browsers, clicking on the button works.

In Firefox, if I click Enter while in text input, it submits the form.
In IE, it does nothing.

How can I make it work with IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly IE likes having an actual submit button, whether that's an `<input type="submit" />` or `<button type="submit">submit me</button>`. Maybe you can put that in there but "out of sight" so you don't see it..

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty text box, with a style of "visibility:hidden;display:none", this is a known issue

Answer (score 0):

This type of form will always work with "Enter":

```
<form ...>
  ...
  <input type="submit" ...>
</form>
```

Make sure you have an `input` of type `submit`.